# CordinatorLayoutによるToolBarのアニメーション

Tags: android, java, android-layout

AndroidStudioのActivity生成テンプレートからTannedActivityのActionBarTabs(with ViewPager)を使ってアクティビティを作成しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="hoge.TabActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

layoutXMLは以上の通りで、ViewPagerにはRecyclerViewを含むページを与えています。
RecyclerViewをスクロールするとToolBarのみが隠れてタブが見えるようになると想定していたのですが、
[image: スワイプしても]

[image: ToolBarが隠れない]
このようにToolBarが上にスライドするばかりで隠れてくれません。
どのようにすれば正しくToolBarのみが隠れてタブだけが残るようになりますでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)を使えば実現できます。

`AppBarLayout`以下のレイアウトを示すと以下の通りです。

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="116dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

まず、TannedActivity テンプレートは横スワイプのみを想定しているので、`AppBarLayout` に `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` の指定がありません。これを追加してステータスバーにめりこむ挙動を直す必要があります。

`CollapsingToolbarLayout` を使う場合、`AppBarLayout` に適切な高さを指定する必要があります。また、`TabLayout`に`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`を追加する必要があります。

`Toolbar` の `app:layout_collapseMode` の指定によって、スクロールに応じて `Toolbar` をどのように変化させるのかを指定します。隠れて欲しい場合は、`none` を指定します。

Comment: 確かに他のスクロール可能ActivityではCollapsingToolbarLayoutが利用されていました。CordinatorLayoutの挙動が未だ理解しきれていませんが、試してみたいと思います。